# recuperar texto da statusbar do onmouseover

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

É possível recuperar o texto da status bar? em Windows.Form em VB6 conseguia.
Gostaria de saber se em C# seria possível

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque no seu form um [**StatusStrip**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.statusstrip(v=vs.110).aspx) e crie nele um [**StatusLabel**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel(v=vs.110).aspx) igual figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecione o [**StatusLabel**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel(v=vs.110).aspx) e vai na guia *Eventos* e de um Duplo Click para criação do evento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após ele criar o evento faça o seguinte código:

```
private void toolStripStatusLabel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{            
    LblRecuperando.Text = toolStripStatusLabel1.Text;
}
```

Debug:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Passando o mouse sobre o texto do [**StatusLabel**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel(v=vs.110).aspx) ele mostrará em um componente [**Label**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx) o mesmo texto.

*Referências:*

- [Classe StatusStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.statusstrip(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ToolStripStatusLabel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: show, obrigado pela resposta, você saberia dizer se é possível agora tb fazer em web? ou seja, passou o mouse por uma url eu recuperar a query montada ?

Comment: pq estarei fazendo um form que abre um browser componente e precisaria tb recuperar a url que é montada por um site de terceiro. como a url é montada via javascript não tem como eu ler o conteúdo do site para conseguir o valor

Comment: @Dorathoto se puder abre outra questão demonstrando essa nova dúvida, é muito interessante, mas, pela minha experiência aqui já é outra dúvida. Pode ser ? (espero que não fique chateado), ai tem mais gente para resolver inclusive eu ... rsrsrsrs)